# Replace within certain parts of XML file?

Tags: xml, text

I have a huge XML file I need to do a Search and Replace operation, but only within the content of the XML, not the tags (so, not change anything between < and >).

Manager having to edit, I have no clue of regular expressions. My editor of choice is Notepad++ but I'll use another tool if I have to.

So in the following snippet:

```
<resource key="Facility_Picker.lblallFacilities">Available **Facilities**</resource>
```

Replace the second 'Facilities', not the first (as that would break the code, obviously).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML and RegExp is a very bad combination (since the structure of XML is inherently non-regular), so I would recommend against regular expressions for this task.

I havent tried this program, but you can see if it works for you:
http://xmlsearchreplace.codeplex.com/
It should be able to do what you want to, and if you can load you file in NotePad++ then it can't be that big..

Comment: The task is almost too trivial to make XSLT worth it. Also, XSLT requires a significant amount of memory to run on big document, so if the document is huge (as said by the OP) XSLT is not a good choice. A good programming solution would probably need to be built on a SAX parser.

Comment: But I guess it wouldn't require too much to make an XSLT sheet that copies all text and attribute notes, and changes the text nodes as required.